# storing javascript source file in sql server database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webpack, varchar, varbinary

I am developping an asp.net web application where an user could upload a javascript source code file and store it into a sqlserver database.

The file he uploads is a javascript file developped by him and then "minified" thanks to webpack. The final file could looks like something like this :

```
window["integration/user"]=function(t){var e={};function r(n){if(e[n])return e[n].exports;var o=e[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return t[n].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,r),o.l=!0,o.exports}return r.m=t,r.c=e,r.d=function(t,e,n){r.o(
```

This is only an extract of the file.
Those files have usually a size of 10 000 bytes (size given by my windows explorer).

So my question was the following :

As varchar and varbinary have the same maximum capacity (8000 chars equivalent to 8000 bytes for varchar and 8000 bytes for varbinary), what would be the best between :

-storing the javascript as plain text in a varchar column

-converting in c# to binary data and then store it into varbinary column

Also, I have done a simple test by trying the second solution, and it's working (I've managed to store it into a varbinary column and then read back javascript from it with c# conversion code), but what I can't understand is how a file of a size of 10000bytes(size given by windows) could be successfully stored in varbinary column of a maximum capacity of 8000 bytes (so smaller than the file) ?

this is my column declaration :

```
[JavascriptBundle] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the confusion is that if you are explicitly defining the lengths of `varchar` or `varbinary` then 8000 is the limit.

However `varchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` both have the maximum lengths of 2^31-1, or 2,147,483,647 bytes. Which are the way you would want to define your database column.

Which of the two you use would depend on your preferred design, `varchar` having the advantage of not having to convert to binary and back.

References:

varchar - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

varbinary - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Ok so in my case and more generally I dont see the interest of using a varbinary instead of a varchar as they have both the same capacity and moreover varbinary just add the complexity of converting to binary and back.

Comment: Absolutely. And if this answered your question please accept it as the answer.